# x86 instructions which load blocks of memory

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have some x86 assembly code. I would like to identify instructions loading memory **so that I can establish how many distinct cache-line blocks are being accessed by the CPU**.

What are the subset of x86 instructions I should be looking out for? Originally I just thought it was all instructions beginning with `mov`, which also loaded a `qword` or `dword`, and includes the `ptr` reference, but I wanted to check first.

Comment: If the code uses SSE or AVX then you might also want to look for `lddqu` or `vlddqu`. Also `vmovXXX` if AVX.

Comment: Anything that has square brackets, except the LEA instruction.

Comment: Do you just mean "load", as in transfer memory into a register, or any kind of memory access that requires use of the bus?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'll update my Q to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks. Bear in mind that RMW operations need to do loading implicitly.

Comment: @KerrekSB updated- so basically I want to try and establish how many distinct blocks of memory are being accessed from a snippet of asm.

Comment: @PaulR I can turn off intrinsic functions if that would make my task easier?

Comment: @user997112: your compiler may generate SSE/AVX code even if you don't use intrinsics - there may also be library code that uses SSE/AVX.

Comment: @PaulR I can specifically disable intrinsics on my compiler

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "disable SSE/AVX code generation" when you say "disable intrinsics", but that still doesn't eliminate the possibility of SIMD-optimised library code (e.g. in `memcpy`). It's not clear what you're trying to achieve though - if you don't care about the code in the libraries you link to then you should be OK.

Comment: @PaulR My end-goal is to establish how many different blocks of memory the CPU processes.

Comment: What do you mean by different blocks? What is a block? When is it different from an other block? Is that like cache lines or pages or regions in linear space as mapped by the BIOS?

Comment: @harold I have edited my question to make it clearer. I'd like to count the number of distinct cache-line sized memory blocks being accessed.

Comment: So what about all the instructions other than explicit loads and stores that access memory directly ?

Comment: @PaulR do they not access the memory using the square bracket notation [x]? This is the essence of my question- is it possible to easily identify instructions (not limited to MOV) which access memory?

Comment: Probably - as a gcc user I'm more familiar with AT&T syntax but Nils suggested earlier in the comments that you may be right on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your methodology is flawed.  The same instruction can access different cache lines.  e.g. `memcpy` only needs a few instructions, but can touch megabytes of memory in a loop.

Looking for memory operands in disassembler output isn't going to get you anywhere, because lots of instructions will load/store the same data, and some instructions in loops will load/store lots of different data.

You need a cache / memory profiler program to find the answer to your ultimate question.